# Auto-Submit Form using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="test.php" method="POST">
  <p>
  <input name="test" value="test" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form>

    <script>

    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function()
    {
    submitform();
    }, 10000);

    function submitform()
    {
      alert('test');
      document.myForm.submit();
    }
    </script>
```

I'm having trouble trying to auto-submit a form every ***10 seconds*** once landed on a page. The form name is myForm `action="test.php"`. I get the `'test'` message but the page doesn't submit the form.

Any solutions besides autoloading the function upon page load?

**FIXED:** Removed (`name="submit"`) from the submit button and it worked smoothly.

Comment: What is `document.myForm` at the time the function is called?

Comment: `<form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="test.php" method="POST">
  <p>
  <input name="test" value="test" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form>`

Comment: Do you have an action defined on your form? Please include the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**You need to specify a frame, a target otherwise your script will vanish on first submit!**

Change `document.myForm` with `document.forms["myForm"]`:

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" target="_myFrame" action="test.php" method="POST">
    <p>
        <input name="test" value="test" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function(){
        var auto = setTimeout(function(){ autoRefresh(); }, 100);

        function submitform(){
          alert('test');
          document.forms["myForm"].submit();
        }

        function autoRefresh(){
           clearTimeout(auto);
           auto = setTimeout(function(){ submitform(); autoRefresh(); }, 10000);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Modified the script, tested, it works, works better with `setTimeout`

Comment: You need to specify a frame, a target otherwise your script will vanish on first submit!

Comment: I don't get it. What am I doing wrong? Uploaded the file at http://wildmedia.ro/auto_submit.php, still only 'test' pops up. Form not submitted.

Comment: remove `name="submit"` from `submit` button because `document.forms["myForm"].submit` sees it as an element

Comment: The form's `id` attribute is not necessary in this example, since the form is accessed by the `name` attribute. (Unless of course you prefer to use `document.getElementById()`, in which case one should specify an `id` attribute instead of `name`.)

Answer (score 11):

Try using `document.getElementById("myForm")` instead of document.myForm.

```
<script>
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() { submitform(); }, 10000);

function submitform()
{
  alert('test');
  document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: How doesn't it work? Do you see an error in the javascript console?

Answer (score 7):

This solution worked for me:

```
<body onload="setTimeout(function() { document.myform.submit() }, 5000)">
   <form action=TripRecorder name="myform">
      <textarea id="result1"  name="res1" value="str1" cols="20" rows="1" ></textarea> <br> <br/>
      <textarea id="result2" name="res2" value="str2" cols="20" rows="1" ></textarea>
   </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution for a **delayed auto submit**:

```
<body onload="setTimeout(function() { document.frm1.submit() }, 5000)">
   <form action="https://www.google.com" name="frm1">
      <input type="hidden" name="q" value="Hello world" />
   </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score -7):

Try this,

```
HtmlElement head = _windowManager.ActiveBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement scriptEl = _windowManager.ActiveBrowser.Document.CreateElement("script");
IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
element.text = "window.onload = function() { document.forms[0].submit(); }";
head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
strAdditionalHeader = "";
_windowManager.ActiveBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("webBrowserControl");
```

Comment: Why should anyone use this code without any explanation? Please describe what this code do in your answer.