# How to automatically submit form if input field value exists?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following form on my site. It's simple, one search input field and one submit button:

```
<form id="search-form" name="search-form" onsubmit="return search()">
  <input type="search" id="query" class="search-field" value="<?php echo $searchQuery;?>">
  <input type="submit" name="search-btn" id="search-btn" value="">
</form>
```

As you can see, in the search field (`id=query`) I have a php which sometimes inserts value into his field.

What I want to do is following:

- If `$searchQuery` doesn't exist (or in other words, if value of search
  field `id=query` is empty, allow user to click on the search button
  manually.
- If `$searchQuery` exist, auto submit the the form (simulate click on
  the search button.

Any solution will help, JavaScript, jQuery or in PHP. I just need to figure out how to auto submit this form when PHP variable `$searchQuery` exists.

Comment: May be this post will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376173/auto-submit-form-using-javascript

Comment: It deals with something different, delayed start. Not entirely applicable. But thanks.

Comment: if the query value filled at the start, then will the form auto submit? since form action is not set it will redirect to the same page, beware of unlimited redirection

Comment: Why not just do a redirect or, even better, do whatever it is that you want to do with that value on this page? There's no point to rendering the form and trying to submit it instantaneously.

Comment: @EdCottrell Sometimes there is value in having the "regular" page flash by, even if it is replaced quickly.

Comment: @manassehkatz I can't think of any scenario in which the proposal described here would offer a good user experience. It would be confusing, at best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are asking specifically on initial page load. Use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   if ($('#query').val() !== '') {
      $('#search-form').submit();
   }
});
```

Comment: yes, this worked like a charm... thank you so much sir, you've just saved my day

Answer (score 3):

You would need to just look to see if the value is populated and submit the form if it is.

**jQuery Version**:

```
$( function() {
    if ( $( '#query' ).val() !== '' ) {
        $( '#search-form' ).submit();
    }
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fe9m8pk3/

**Javascript Version**:

```
function ready( fn ) {
    if ( document.attachEvent ? document.readyState === 'complete' : document.readyState !== 'loading' ) {
      fn();
    } else {
      document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', fn );
    }
}

ready( function() {
    if ( document.getElementById( 'query' ).value != '' ) {
        document.getElementById( 'search-form' ).submit();
    }
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qeo25yu1/

Comment: excellent, this was the final solution, I just accepted the shorter version

Comment: Yeahhhhhh I didn't see the ID on there - I usually list the IDs first, so my brain  just went with the more complicated selector :P

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="javascript/text">
var query = document.getElementById('query');
if(query.value != ''){
    //do your submit
}
function yoursubmitfunctionname(){
    //do your submit
}
query.addEventListener('change',yoursubmitfunctionname);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will submit form if character length minimum fullfiled using Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var minimum_character = 7;

    $('#query').on('propertychange input', function (e)
    {
        var valueChanged = false;

        if(e.type=='propertychange')
        {
            valueChanged = e.originalEvent.propertyName=='value';
        }
        else
        {
            valueChanged = true;
        }

        if(valueChanged)
        {
            str_length = $('#query').val().length;
            if(str_length == minimum_character)
            {
                $("#search-form").submit();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This works only if I start typing to a field and reach 7 characters or whatever lenght is specified. But it  $searchQuery is automatically prefilled through PHP, it doesn't do anything... looks like this is somehow tied to typing, instead of monitoring the value.