# filling form field automatically, html

Tags: html

There is a form:

```
    <form id="1" action="file.php" method="POST">
        <textarea type="text" name="stream" style="width:80%;" rows="7" cols="40"></textarea>
 
        <br /><br /><br />
        
        <br /><br />
        <label for="number"><span style="font-size: 30pt;">number of results:</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="number" style="width:70px; margin: 50pt; ">
        <br />
        
        <br /><br /><br />
   
   
        <input type="submit" value="Submit form">
</form>
```

A user is supposed to enter value of both form elements: `stream`, `number`

My objective is to automate the process by setting e.g. `stream="test"` and `number="5"` and then open file.php.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: You wanna auto submit and by setting you mean set a value?

Comment: Yes. I think so.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376173/auto-submit-form-using-javascript

Comment: https://www.tutorialexample.com/a-beginners-guide-to-javascript-auto-submit-html-form-javascript-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be the result you want.
You just add the "Attribute value"

```
<textarea type="text" name="stream" style="width:80%;" rows="7" cols="40">test</textarea>
<input type="text" name="number" value="5" style="width:70px; margin: 50pt;">
```

or

```
<input type="number" name="number" value="5" style="width:70px; margin: 50pt;">
```

Comment: You may need to use javascript events onchanges. so that it works automatically once the information is filled in.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this? You will need to use JS to submit

Set values on server

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.getElementById("form1").submit();
})
```

```html
<form id="form1" action="file.php" method="POST">
  <textarea type="text" name="stream" style="width:80%;" rows="7" cols="40">test</textarea>
  <br />
  <label for="number"><span style="font-size: 30pt;">number of results:</span></label>
  <input type="text" name="number" style="width:70px; margin: 50pt;" value="5">
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit form">
</form>
```

or set values on client

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.querySelector("[name=stream]").value="test";
  document.querySelector("[name=number]").value="5";
  document.getElementById("form1").submit();
})
```

```html
<form id="form1" action="file.php" method="POST">
  <textarea type="text" name="stream" style="width:80%;" rows="7" cols="40"></textarea>
  <br />
  <label for="number"><span style="font-size: 30pt;">number of results:</span></label>
  <input type="text" name="number" style="width:70px; margin: 50pt; ">
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit form">
</form>
```